# Can/Should I put a comma before "for" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, grammar, learning

- China’s domestic brands have made huge strides in the years since 2012, creating new features and products that take into account what Chinese users want, **for** a small fraction of the price.

i can't understand the usage of "for" in this sentence. Is this usage a conjunction or a preposition?

Comment: The comma separates the prepositional phrase starting with *for*. Without it, the sentence would say that the Chinese users want (the products) for a small fraction (or for other purposes). The original means "creating new...products...for a small fraction."

Comment: The comma helps separate a new phrase. You could also write "... what Chinese users want, and at lower prices..."

Comment: @YosefBaskin thank you for your help

Comment: Quite apart from any grammar involved, the sentence arguably doesn't make sense. New (one might well assume 'novel') products cannot felicitously cost 'a small fraction of the price' as they haven't a comparator. 'We've invented a squirdle-extractor, and at a fraction of the price!'